# in E&W, what is the "pre-action protocol"?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, civil-procedure

In [Statutes of limitations and the pre-action protocol (PAP)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/82942/statutes-of-limitations-and-the-pre-action-protocol/82962#82962) it is stated that the "pre-action protocol (PAP) must be completed before a case is brought to court in England-and-Wales. Just what is the "pre-action protocol" in E&W, when is it required, and how long does it typically take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-action protocols are part of the Civil Procedure Rules (CPR) which governs proceedings in the County Court, High Court, and Court of Appeal (see [Rule 2.1](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part02#2.1)).

They set out what the parties should do *before* initiating proceedings in court. Being practice directions, they are not rules, but you ignore them at your peril; failing to do so will not affect the outcome of your case but can have cost implications or, in the most severe cases, result in sanctions (see paragraphs 13 - 15 [here](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct)).

There is a [general pre-action protocol](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct) and a set of specific pre-action protocols for particular types of cases. If there is a specific protocol for your case, you follow that, otherwise you follow the general one (see [paragraph 2](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct)).

The full list of specific pre-action protocols can be found [here](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct). Note that there is another list contained within the general pre-action protocol at [paragraph 18](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct#18.1) but this list is not complete. This is rather unfortunate because paragraph 18 contains the phrase "the table sets out the protocols currently in force" and, below the table, "Updated: Wednesday, 6 April 2022" (which implies, incorrectly, that any older protocols not appearing in the table are not currently in force). I suggest using the first list.

**"How long does it typically take?"**

This varies depending on the protocol being followed. See for example paragraph 6 of the [general protocol](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct#6.1) which, without being prescriptive, suggests that a reasonable time for a defendant to respond to a pre-action letter is 14 days in a simple case and 3 months in a complex one.

**"pre-action protocol (PAP) must be completed before a case is brought to court in England-and-Wales"**

This is incorrect. Per [paragraph 17](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/pd_pre-action_conduct#17.1) of the general pre-action protocol, if you are close to the limitation period, you can start proceedings and then apply for a stay to give you time to comply with the protocol.